# How to interpret dummy variable in ML prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, feature-selection, dummy-variables

I am working on a binary classification problem where I have a mix of continuous and categorical variables.

Categorical variables were created by me using `get_dummies` function in pandas.

Now my questions are,

1) I see that there is a parameter called `drop_first` which usually is given the value `True`. Why do we have to do this? 
Let's say for the purpose of example, we have 2 values in gender column namely `Male`,`Female`. If I use `drop_first=True`, it returns only one column. like `gender_male` with binary `1` and `0` as values
For example, If my feature importance returns `gender_male` as an important feature, Am I right to infer that it is only `Male` gender that influences the outcome (because male is denoted as 1 and female is 0) and female (0's) don't impact the model outcome? or 0's in general doesn't play any role in ML model predictions?

2) Let's say my gender has 3 values for example `Male`,`Female`,`Transgender`. In this case if I use `drop_first=True`, it would only returns two columns

`gender_male` with 1 and 0  - Here `0` represents `Transgender` right?

`gender_female` with 1 and 0 - Here `0` represents `Transgender` right?

3) What's the disadvantage of not using `drop_first=True`? Is it only about the increase in number of columns

Can you help me with the above queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Using `drop_first=True` is more common in statistics and often referred to as "dummy encoding" while using `drop_first=False` gives you "one hot-encoding" which is more common in ML. For algorithmic approaches like Random Forests it does not make a difference. Also see "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python"; Mueller, Guido; 2016:

> The one-hot encoding we use is quite similar, but not identical, to
>   the dummy encoding used in statistics. For simplicity, we encode
>   each category with a different binary feature. In statistics, it is common
>   to encode a categorical feature with k different possible values
>   into k–1 features (the last one is represented as all zeros). This is
>   done to simplify the analysis (more technically, this will avoid making
>   the data matrix rank-deficient).

However, using dummy encoding on a binary variable does not mean that a `0` has no relevance. If `gender_male` has high importance that does not generally say anything about the importance of `gender_male==0` vs `gender_male==1`. It is **variable** importance and accordingly calculated per variable. If you, for example, use impurity based estimates in Trees it only gives you the average reduction in impurity achieved by splitting on this very variable.

Moreover, if your gender variable is binary, `gender_male==1` is equivalent to `gender_female==0`. Therefore from a high variable importance of `gender_male` you cannot infer that being female (or not) is not relevant.

2) In this case `gender_male==0 AND gender_female==0` means Transgender is true.

3) see 1). For algorithmic approaches in ML there is no statistical disadvantage using one-hot-encoding. (as pointed out in the comments it might even be advantageous since tree-based models can directly split on all features when none is being dropped)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Upvoted. Sorry I didn't get your point regarding `gender_male` . Yes, my gender is a binary variable and I see this as a important variable. Now if I have to make an interpretation of my model, how do I do it? Because it has 1 which indicates `male` and `0` indicates `female`. So can you please help me understand this much better in ordinary layman terms for interpretation part alone? I understood the first half of point 1.

Comment: should I understand that `gender being male` can influence outcome more than `gender being female`? At the end of the day, there has to be some interpretation or usefulness of `gender_male` and am trying to know what it is

Comment: What I meant is that if gender is a binary variable you cannot make any inference whether being male (or not) is more important than being female (or not) since these two are equivalent. If you use dummy encoding (`drop_first=True`) and your resulting independent variable `gender_male` turns out to be of high importance, then you can only infer that gender is important for your model.

Comment: fantastic got it.

Comment: I disagree that `drop_first` doesn't make a difference in random forest, when the original variable has more than two levels.  In order to select for the missing category, a tree has to make several subsequent selections of _not_ each (other) dummy variable.

Comment: @BenReiniger That's a good point. I've edited the last sentence of my answer accordingly.